# closure of rationalsmin topology

Tags: general-topology, field-theory

Why is the closure of the rationals Q,  the reals R ?

Is it because the irrational numbers are only considered part of the set of rationals Q in its closure?

Aside: Good thorough website to learn Latex?

Comment: Because every irrational number can be approximated by a sequence of rational numbers.

Comment: Is that the same as saying that the irrationals are limit points?

Comment: Yep, you are right.